# Adding cells to UITableView when all cells are static (designed in storyboard)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with 5 sections. All sections contain 2 static cells. What I want to achieve is to insert a new cell to one of my section when user taps some button. I know how to add cells with animation when `UITableView` contains only dynamic cells, I have no idea how to do this with 100% static `UITableView`.

The point is to that in one of my cells I have a text input and a button. After user taps the button, input content must be validated. If validation fails then I want to add an extra cell with error info.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have you tried using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`?, I haven't tested it but it could work

Comment: This method works great if you are working with dynamic cells. Why? Because you have access data source NSArray which you have to modify before you invoke insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:. Nevertheless thanks for our suggestion, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you able to find how to add static cells using story board.Show configure table view as static cells and create outlets according to your app design.

[image]

Comment: I think description of my problem hasn't been good enough. You see, I already have table with static cells and what I need to do is to add dynamic cell to existing tabel at runtime, depending on textfield validation.